# Cetificates for a gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway

Let's say I have 5 distinct APIs, which will all be deployed to AWS API Gateway.

I have a root domain on Route 53, let's call it `example-domain.com`. My 'dilemma' now is whether I should create a subdomain for every API (`api-1.example-domain.com`, `api-2.example-domain.com`) or use the root domain and add routes to distinguish between APIs (`example-domain.com/api-1/route/to/resources`, `example-domain.com/api-2/route/to/resources`.

Are there any drawbacks or advantages for these two approaches?

Additionally, what is better: using a single TLS certificate for each subdomain (which corresponds to the strategy of using the root domain only) or using a separate TLS certificate when having multiple sub domains, one for each API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For APIs it would be better go with separate domains like `api-1.example-domain.com, api-2.example-domain.com` which I have seen in multiple organizations.

Also create single SSL/TLS certificate with the domain of

```
*.example.com -
```

Above option can give you multiple domains with single certificate, but it is limited to the single level domains I.E. api1.example.com, Not for api1.dev.example.com.
this is better option for your workflow.

I hope this helps, do comment for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your input. One question: What do you mean by 'better for my workflow' with regards to using a single SSL/TLS certificate with a domain containing a wildcard?

Comment: Better means, you won't have to worry about every domain with specific SSL/TLS certificates. Just add CNAME with whatever domain you want and it will work fine.